# Designing right RestAPI architecture for complex query

Tags: .net, rest, architecture

I am a newcomer to RestAPI architecture and I am a little confused to understand it.

I always use simple Get/Post for all my needs. I am researching about rest API to use in my new projects and one question which I couldn't find an answer is about using RestApi for the complex query. For example one of my queries is gotten from Multi Joins (from stored procedure or `Include()` in Entity Framework) and the view model (DTO) has many nested Objects.

If I want to design RestAPI for such queries how can I do it? And is it a good idea to use Rest API for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the rest api in the same way as you have before. A GET request with all of the parameters needed for the query should suffice.

If it is the case that you feel that the request is looking too cluttered or too long, you could implement hashing of the request to your API to help improve security, i.e. instead of:

*/endpoint?a=1&b=2&c=3%...*

something like:

*/endpoint?{hash}*